# Python script crashing after opening chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, import, package

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, chrome


def startchrome(url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches',['enable-logging'])
    driver = Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url)
```

this is for backend.py
and I run chrome by importing backend to main script and running by:

```
backend.startchrome(url)
```

Chrome opens but main crashes (says is not responding)
Thanks

Comment: Is the URL up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify `startChrome()` method a bit :

```
def startchrome(url):
   executable_path = r"C:\\Users\\Inc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe"
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
   options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path, options=options)
   driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

replace `google.com` with `url` string